# Como aumentar o tamanho da fonte de um EditText de acordo com o tamanho da tela?

Tags: android, css-font-size

Gostaria que o tamanho da fonte fosse proporcional ao tamanho da tela do dispositivo que executará a aplicação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

você pode criar um arquivo `dimens.xml` para cada tipo/resolução de tela:

1) Crie uma pasta `values` para as resoluções que você quer tratar de forma individual, exemplo: `values-hdpi`, `values-mdpi` etc.

2) Dentro do arquivo `dimens.xml` de cada pasta crie um item `dimen` (com o mesmo nome em todas):

```
<dimen name="txt_size">12sp</dimen>
```

3) Agora, dentro do seu `EditText`:

```
android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size"
```

Você pode verificar a lista completa de resoluções através da documentação oficial:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html